# Hadoop Hive query to merge rows into one row

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need one hive query which merge same EAN rows into one record in table based on priority which is another table.

table: products
   [image]

As shown in the above image I have different products from different sources(sourceid) and I want only one row by merging all sources data based on below priority. If priority "1" source doesn't provide any field info, that field info  will be taken from  priority "2" source.

Table: priority

```
node_id Source_id   Priority
1        62          1
1        303         2
1        202         3
```

I am expecting results as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can actually use collect udf to collect all the other fields based on one field.

or you can use some nested arrays or struct to get the data into single row, If you don't want to loose any data.

Comment: Thanks Ankush... I used collect_list  and  brickhouse udf  array_index  to get complete solution.